# How to use recursion to sum/add the number between x and y?

Tags: recursion, prolog

I would like to ask as to how would you be able to make a recursion that would add from your starting number (x) up to the end (y).

E.G. = summation(Ans, 1, 5).
Ans = 15

(1+2+3+4+5) = 15 //is what should occur in the recursion

So far what I've done is this:

```
sumFrom(Sum, X ,Y) :- X>Y, !, write('Start should not be greater than End').
sumFrom(Sum, X ,Y) :- Sum is X+Y,
        Next is X+1,
        sumFrom(Sum, Next, Y).
```

I am still new to prolog so please be gentle.

Answer (score 4):

Since pure (the declarative subset of) Prolog doesn't have loops and mutable variables, performing arithmetic can be tricky. I think it's worth to learn about [libraries](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate), when the basic has become clear:

```
?- aggregate(sum(N),between(1,5,N),S).
S = 15.
```

Comment: yes, both Barney and Tudor are more on point. I had little to add to their good answers, but I think that as a newbie you could appreciate my hint about extensive available libraries...

Answer (score 3):

Been a while since I did Prolog, but what immediately jumps out is that you do not have a termination rule: as written, your program will keep incrementing Next until it is greater than Y, and then return the error condition. So you need something like:

```
sumFrom(Sum, X ,Y) :- X=Y, Sum=X.
```

Next, You don't want to calculate `Sum is X + Y` each time: for `sumFrom(Ans, 1, 5)` this would calculate 1 + 5, 2 + 5, 3 + 5, 4 + 5, 5 + 5, with each calculation just replacing the previous value. To accumulate the total, you want to calculate `Sum is Sum + X`.

Finally, I think you need a different variable for the recursive Sum, and need to re-order your clauses so all dependent variables are resolved by the time each `is` is evaluated.

So you end up with something like this:

```
sumFrom(Sum, X ,Y) :- X>Y, !, write('Start should not be greater than End').
sumFrom(Sum, X ,Y) :- X=Y, Sum=X.
sumFrom(Sum, X ,Y) :- Next is X+1,
        sumFrom(Sum1, Next, Y),
        Sum is Sum1+X.
```

Like I said, bit rusty on Prolog so may not be the best solution, but hope it helps.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

A tail-recursive solution is more efficient in terms of stack usage:

```
sumFrom(X, Y, Acc, Acc):-
    X > Y, !.
sumFrom(X, Y, Acc, Sum):-
    Acc1 is X + Acc,
    X1 is X + 1,
    sumFrom(X1, Y, Ac11, Sum).

sumFrom(X, Y, Sum):-
    sumFrom(X, Y, 0, Sum).
```

The first rule says that the accumulated sum should be the final sum if `X` is greater than `Y`. If that is not the case (i.e. `X =< Y`), then you add `X` to the accumulated sum and increment `X` before trying to satisfy the recursive goal.

```
?- sumFrom(2, 10, Sum).
Sum = 54.
```

---

*Note*: the **red cut** used above assumes that `Sum` is a free variable in a `sumFrom/4` query. Otherwise, the program might loop forever instead of failing for queries like `sumFrom(2, 10, -1)`.

If you want to cover this type of queries too, consider removing the **red cut** and add the `X =< Y` condition to the second rule.

```
?- sumFrom(2, 10, 55).
false.

?- sumFrom(2, 10, 54).
true ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
sum_of_range(X,X,X) .  % the "sum" of a single-item range is that single item.
sum_of_range(X,Y,S) :- % to get the sum of a multiple item range...
  X < Y ,              % - the lower bound must actually be a lower bound,
  X1 is X+1 ,          % - increment X
  sum(X1,Y,S1) ,       % - compute the sum of that smaller range
  S is X+X1            % - the sum is X + the sum of the smaller range.
  .                    %
```

This will [eventually] blow up with a stack overflow, given a range of sufficient size. Another approach is to exploit *tail recursion* which effectively converts the recursion into iteration (and thus will operate over a range of any size:

```
sum_of_range(X,Y,S) :- sum1(X,Y,0,S) .

sum1(X,X,T,S) :- S is T+X .
sum1(X,Y,T,S) :-
  X < Y ,
  T1 is T+X ,
  X1 is X+1 ,
  sum1(X1,Y,T1,S)
  .
```

A third approach might be to build a prolog term that is an arithmetic expression and, at the end, evaluate it to find the sum:

```
sum_of_range(X,Y,S) :-    % to sum a range of values...
  summation_term(X,Y,T) , % - construct an arithmetic term
  S is T .                % - and evaluate it.

summation_term(X,X,X) .    % the term for a single value is itself.
summation_term(X,Y,X+T) :- % otherwise...
  X < Y ,                  % - if X is less than Y
  X1 is X+1 ,              % - increment X
  summation_term(X1,Y,T)   % - and recurse down.
  .
```

You might note that this doesn't buy you much over something like

```
findall( N, between(X,Y,N), Ns ) , sumlist(Ns,S)
```